# how to concatenate dataframes in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have a dictionary with size of 8,
each key (h3-h10) has a dataframe as value.

I want to do pd.concat multiple time through all my dataframes.
I did merge 2 dataframes with simple pd.concat, but I don't know how to iterate through all my dataframes

```
df=pd.concat([data['h3'][0],data['h4'][0]])
print(df)
```

it gives this as
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqhOG.png)

my first idea is creating empty dataframe, then using for loop, appending all the rest of dataframes
I have h3-h10 as dataframes

```
qhn = []
i=0
for k in data:
  for i in range (0:len(data)-1):
    qhn = pd.concat([qhn,data[f'h{i}}'][0]])
    i+=1
print(qhn)
```

EDIT:

I was thinking of creating a series of dataframes with help from for loop,
then do pd.concate(series):

```
for k in data:
  ser.set_value(data[f'{k}'][0])
print(Series)
```

but it also gave me error :

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_value'

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate all using `dict.values` to call all values at once:

```
out = pd.concat(data.values(), ignore_index=True)
```

However, it seems `data.values()` contains lists of DataFrames, in which case, you can flatten the lists using a generator expression then concatenate:

```
out = pd.concat((df for lst in data.values() for df in lst), ignore_index=True)
```

`data` looks like:

```
data = {'h3': [df3], 'h4': [df4], ..., 'h10': [df10]}
```

where each of `df3, df4, ... df10` is a DataFrame. Then since `data.values()` is an object that shows a list of all the values in it, it's a list of list of DataFrames. However, `pd.concat` works on only on Series or DataFrame objects, so you need to create a single list of DataFrames, instead of a list of list of DataFrames. So you flatten it using the generator expression:

```
(df for lst in data.values() for df in lst)
```

and pass it to `pd.concat` to concatenate.

Comment: the second expression works! thank you :D
could please explain a bit what you did in second expression?

Comment: @PieterSandiWijaya updated. see the answer for more explanation

Comment: @PieterSandiWijaya if your question is sufficiently answered, please accept an answer that best suits to your needs by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `data.values()` to get a list of all the dataframes:

```
qhn = pd.concat(data.values())
```

Comment: It gave me this error message:

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: Sorry, dumb mistake on my part. Check the answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

There could be two scenarios to store this base `data` :

Scenario 1: Where you store the DataFrame directly as values in the dictionary:

`data1 = {'h1':df1, 'h2':df2, 'h3':df3...}`

In this kind of scenario, you could simply expand your logic of creating a first data frame with the first iteration and then keep appending the **value** while traversing through the values and using `.append` like this :

```
data1 = {'h1':df1,'h2':df2,'h3':df3}

counter = 0
for value in data1.values():
    if counter == 0:
        output = value
        counter = 1
    else:
        output = output.append(value)
```

Scenario 2: Where you store the DataFrame names within the list in the dictionary :

`data2 = {'h1':[df1],'h2':[df2],'h3':[df3] ...}`

Here, you could again expand the above same logic but access the **value** using the index [0] and hence create the first data frame and then keep appending the further iterations with traversals through the value[0] and using `.append` like this :

```
data2 = {'h1':[df1],'h2':[df2],'h3':[df3]}

counter = 0
for value in data2.values():
    if counter == 0:
        output = value[0]
        counter = 1
    else:
        output = output.append(value[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easiest way to concat dataframes stored in a dictionary.

```py
pd.concat([v for k, v in data.items()], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

# One might want to keep the key value:
df = pd.DataFrame()
for k, v in data.items():
    v["key"] = k
    df = pd.concat([df, v], ignore_index=True)
df
```